# Doing something after running a function n times

Tags: python

I've asked questions regarding this project before. I'm almost done, but I need one more thing. It's about water spillage in pipes. It reads from two temperature sensors, and calculate a temperature difference as well. It should notify by email after a certain number of measurements, if the difference is normal or you need to take action. So far I've managed to send an email after one measurement. But a tempdifference is not unusual in pipes, so I want to notify after a certain number of measurements. This is what I have so far:

```
def aflaes_raa_data():
    f1 = open(fil1, "r")
    f2 = open(fil2, "r")
    linjer1 = f1.readlines()
    f1.close()
    linjer2 = f2.readlines()
    f2.close()
    return linjer1, linjer2


def udregn_temp(raw):
   equals_pos = raw[1].find("t=")
   if equals_pos != -1:
       temp_string = raw[1][equals_pos + 2:]
       temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
       return temp_c


def aflaes_temp():
    linjer1, linjer2 = aflaes_raa_data()
    while linjer1[0].strip()[-3:] != "YES":
        time.sleep(0.2)
    linjer1, linjer2 = aflaes_raa_data()
    temp1 = udregn_temp(linjer1)
    temp2 = udregn_temp(linjer2)
    return "Sensor 1: %d" % temp1 + " grader", "Sensor 2: %d" % temp2 + " grader"


def temp_diff():
    linjer1, linjer2 = aflaes_raa_data()
    temp1, temp2 = udregn_temp(linjer1), udregn_temp(linjer2)
    print("Temperaturforskellen er: ")
    return abs(temp1-temp2)


def send_mail(afsender, password, modtager, emne, email_tekst):
    if 0 < temp_diff() < 4:
        send_mail("something@gmail.com", "password", "something@gmail.com", "Besked fra din vandmåler",
        "Afløbsrør: Temperaturforskellen er lige nu %d, og er højere end grænsen . Handling påkrævet!" % (
                temp_diff()))
    else:
        send_mail(EMAIL_FROM, PASSWORD, EMAIL_TO, "Besked fra din vandmåler",
            "Afløbsrør: "
            "Temperaturforskellen "
            "er lige nu "
            "%d, og er på tæt på 0" % (temp_diff()))


while True:
    print(aflaes_temp())
    print(temp_diff())
    time.sleep(2)
```

I've tried with a for loop

```
for i in range(10):
    if 0 < temp_diff() < 4:
        send_mail("something@gmail.com", "password", "something@gmail.com", "Besked fra din vandmåler",
              "Afløbsrør: Temperaturforskellen er lige nu %d, og er højere end grænsen . Handling påkrævet!" % (
                  temp_diff()))
    else:
        send_mail("something@gmail.com", "password", "something@gmail.com", "Besked fra din vandmåler",
              "Afløbsrør: "
              "Temperaturforskellen "
              "er lige nu "
              "%d, og er på tæt på 0" % (temp_diff()))
```

And a nested loop

```
for i in range(10):
    aflaes_temp()
    for n in range(1):
        if 0 < temp_diff() < 4:
           send_mail("something@gmail.com", "password", "something@gmail.com", "Besked fra din vandmåler",
          "Afløbsrør: Temperaturforskellen er lige nu %d, og er højere end grænsen . Handling påkrævet!" % (
              temp_diff()))
        else:
          send_mail("something@gmail.com", "password", "something@gmail.com", "Besked fra din vandmåler",
          "Afløbsrør: "
          "Temperaturforskellen "
          "er lige nu "
          "%d, og er på tæt på 0" % (temp_diff()))
```

But then I just get the output of `temp_diff` a couple of times and then an email. I've looked around on the internet, but I can only find examples of running functions n times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I have understood your question correctly, instead of sending email instantly you want to observe 3-4 measurements. And based on that measurement, you want to take a decision.

There are many ways that can be achieved. I am providing a solution where you will monitor `theSampleCount` number of measurements and take the `median` of the sample. If the median value is within range then you can send email.

```py
import statistics
while True:
    theSampleCount = 10 # you will monitor 10 samples
    samples = []
    while(theSampleCount>0):
        theSampleCount -= 1
        temp_diff_var = temp_diff()
        samples.append(temp_diff_var)
        print(aflaes_temp())
        print(temp_diff_var)
        time.sleep(2) # delay after which you want to measure
    # now you have 4 samples, you will take the median
    median_value = statistics.median(samples)
    # now apply your logic here on median_value. 
    # based on that you can determine whether to send an email or not
    if 0 < median_value < 4:
        send_mail("something@gmail.com", "password", "something@gmail.com", "Besked fra din vandmåler",
        "Afløbsrør: Temperaturforskellen er lige nu %d, og er højere end grænsen . Handling påkrævet!" % (
                median_value))
   else:
        send_mail(EMAIL_FROM, PASSWORD, EMAIL_TO, "Besked fra din vandmåler",
            "Afløbsrør: "
            "Temperaturforskellen "
            "er lige nu "
            "%d, og er på tæt på 0" % (median_value))
```

Here is the full code

```py
def aflaes_raa_data():
    f1 = open(fil1, "r")
    f2 = open(fil2, "r")
    linjer1 = f1.readlines()
    f1.close()
    linjer2 = f2.readlines()
    f2.close()
    return linjer1, linjer2


def udregn_temp(raw):
   equals_pos = raw[1].find("t=")
   if equals_pos != -1:
       temp_string = raw[1][equals_pos + 2:]
       temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.0
       return temp_c


def aflaes_temp():
    linjer1, linjer2 = aflaes_raa_data()
    while linjer1[0].strip()[-3:] != "YES":
        time.sleep(0.2)
    linjer1, linjer2 = aflaes_raa_data()
    temp1 = udregn_temp(linjer1)
    temp2 = udregn_temp(linjer2)
    return "Sensor 1: %d" % temp1 + " grader", "Sensor 2: %d" % temp2 + " grader"


def temp_diff():
    linjer1, linjer2 = aflaes_raa_data()
    temp1, temp2 = udregn_temp(linjer1), udregn_temp(linjer2)
    #print("Temperaturforskellen er: ")
    return abs(temp1-temp2)

import statistics
while True:
    theSampleCount = 10 # you will monitor 10 samples
    samples = []
    while(theSampleCount>0):
        theSampleCount -= 1
        temp_diff_var = temp_diff()
        samples.append(temp_diff_var)
        print(aflaes_temp())
        print(f"Temperaturforskellen er: {temp_diff_var}")
        time.sleep(2) # delay after which you want to measure
    # now you have 4 samples, you will take the median
    median_value = statistics.median(samples)
    # now apply your logic here on median_value. 
    # based on that you can determine whether to send an email or not
    if 0 < median_value < 4:
        send_mail("something@gmail.com", "password", "something@gmail.com", "Besked fra din vandmåler",
        "Afløbsrør: Temperaturforskellen er lige nu %d, og er højere end grænsen . Handling påkrævet!" % (
                median_value))
   else:
        send_mail(EMAIL_FROM, PASSWORD, EMAIL_TO, "Besked fra din vandmåler",
            "Afløbsrør: "
            "Temperaturforskellen "
            "er lige nu "
            "%d, og er på tæt på 0" % (median_value))
```

Comment: Almost correct. I want to keep running `aflaes_temp` (means read_temp) and `temp_diff` and after, lets say ten measurements, send an email.

Comment: does the above solution will solve your problem?

Comment: Not quite. Although, I'm not sure that I've done it correctly. Put the whole if statement under `median_value`. And I still want to print `aflaes_temp` and `temp_diff` to the console. So like 10 instances of `aflaes_temp` and `temp_diff` and then send an email that can be either of the two mentioned.

Comment: @Techguy how about now?

Comment: Almost there. It print it in this order: 
Temperaturforskellen er: 
('Sensor 1: 22 grader', 'Sensor 2: 22 grader')
0.062000000000001165

I want it the other way around:
('Sensor 1: 22 grader', 'Sensor 2: 22 grader')
Temperaturforskellen er: 
0.062000000000001165

And also it should automatically send an email after 10 samples, and ot when i manually stop the code.

Comment: Check the full code. It will send an email after 10 samples.

Comment: Why do I need a `median` though? Wouldn

Comment: suppose the accepted range of your sensor is from 90 to 100. Now you take 5 samples. The sample values are 95, 99, 105, 106, 500. Now if you take the average, it will become 181, but the median is 105. Mean is out of range and doesn't represent the sample. It is simply from statistical reasoning.

Comment: I'm not sure that I need the median. The purpose is to find out if there's still a temp_diff after n samples. So if there's still a significant difference after n samples then send a mail. And I've just figured out that it might be enough with `if 0 < value:`